# Why aren't these while loops mixing the numbers I am giving them?

Tags: c, while-loop, nested

I am trying to make a simple program that goes through each number starting from 2 and to see if it is an armstrong number or not. Meaning, I should get a match at 153. However, I have been trying to have these 2 nested loops work together but I am not seeing something.

I tried having 2 loops. I tried having only one loop. I know that it would be easier to ask for input, but I want to go through each number and break the loop when I find the first number that comes in the way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int remainder_, cubic_power, sum_, placeholder;

    bool check = true;
    int i=2;
    while(check){
        placeholder = i;
        printf("i is %d and placeholder is %d \n", i, placeholder);
        while(placeholder!=0){
            remainder_ = placeholder%10;
            cubic_power = remainder_*remainder_*remainder_;
            sum_+=cubic_power;

            placeholder = placeholder/10;
            Sleep(1500);
         }
    printf("Number being test %d \n", placeholder);
    printf("Sum is %d \n", sum_);
    if (sum_ == i){
        printf("%d is your number \n");
        bool check=false;
    }
    i++;
    printf("i is %d \n", i);

}
```

}

It should break at 153 but it does not.

Comment: You are quite sleepy. What makes you think that it has already passed 153 without breaking, instead of still sleeping towards it? Did you debug your program to observe what exactly it is doing at 153?

Comment: What's the point of `Sleep` in the loop? Are you trying to slow down your calculation? Also what is the point of the underscores in your names? It is making the code less readable.

Comment: Could you explain how the title is supposed to describe what the question is about? I don't see a connection.

Comment: There are some improvements should be made , like you can initialize the variables to 0 and as others said sleep is unnecssary one . Instread you can use getchar() and more print statements to see what is going on.

Comment: I used sleep only to slow down the printing so I can see what's happening. Another user has been helpful and showed me the right way. Thank you all.

Comment: Also, the line "bool check = false;" creates a *new* variable called "check", totally unrelated to the one that controls your outer loop, sets it, then throws it away when it goes out of scope. I assume you mean "check = false;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `sum_` each time you are starting to test a new number.

In `bool check=false;`, delete `bool`. That defines a new instance of something named `check`, different from the previous thing named `check`, so it does not change the value of that previous `check`. Removing the type, `bool`, makes it an assignment statement that changes the previous object rather than a definition of a new object.

In `printf("%d is your number \n");`, insert `, i` after the format string and before the closing parenthesis.

Turn on compiler warnings and errors and pay attention to them.